# How to receive Access Token for OAuth 2.0 authorization using Simple.OData.Client, Grant Type 'authorization code'

Tags: oauth, simple.odata.client

I am trying to POST a payload to the web server using **Simple.OData.Client** in .Net application.

I have the following parameters:

- Authorization = 'OAuth 2.0'
- Grand Type = 'Authorization Code'
- Callback URL = 'https://myserver.com/*'
- Auth URL = 'https://myserver.com/auth'
- Access Token URL = 'https://myserver/token'
- Client ID = 'id'
- Client Secret = 'secret'
- Scope = 'openid'
- Token Name = 'name'

I also have URL and endpoint for POST.

Using these parameters I can get Access Token and POST data successfully using **Postman**, the problem is to implement that on C#.
As I understand it has to be 2 steps process: get Access Token, post.

Could someone provide code for getting Access Token?

Comment: Hi, would you be able to provide a sample repo

Comment: thta's what I am looking for: Example of 'Autorization code' flow on c#